# Oracle Update script for multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using this script

```
update arinvt 
set cycle_cound_code = 'A'
where std_cost > 200, 
 
set cycle_count_code = 'B'
where std_cost > 100, 

set cycle_count_code 'C' 
where std_cost > 50, 
else 'D'
```

So it seems it worked for Sap Crystal Reports however it will not work in my oracle database.
I am getting this error message: ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended.
I am having trouble figuring out where I went wrong?
Also if I run the just the first  line:

```
update arinvt 
set cycle_cound_code = 'A'
where std_cost > 200
```

this seems to work until I added the rest of it.

Comment: An UPDATE has one SET and one optional WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` *expression* instead:

```
update arinvt 
set cycle_cound_code =
  case when std_cost > 200 then 'A' 
       when std_cost > 100 then 'B'
       when std_cost > 50  then 'C'
       else 'D'
  end
```